# Generating report as txt file - How to set the exact positions and sizes for texts in Column Header and Detail bands

Tags: java, jasper-reports, fixed-width

We have a requirement where text reports are to be generated using *JasperReports*.
The precision has to be accurate, sample format is as follows

[image]

1. Header user name has to start at column 0.
2. Header last accessed must start at column 23.
3. Header is active must start at column 34.
4. Line separator must have 8 characters (---) and start at column 22
5. Name filed must be left aligned and start at column 1
6. Points field must be right aligned and end in column 45, with precision to 1 place.

The *JasperReports*, *exportToText* method does not satisfy the above criteria and repeated adjustment of the *.jrxml* is not serving the purpose.
We adjusted the character width and character height as well, but still there is incorrect spacing between rows and columns.

Does *JasperReports API* support such precision in text formats?
Is there any other API which can help us in achieving this format?

Comment: `text reports` - What exporter are you trying?

Comment: @AlexK We are using JRTextExporter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve your design with *JasperReports*.

### Steps in solving task.

1. The first step. *We should the numbers of characters in row and the number of rows on page.*
   We can use pair of [*net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.page.width*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.page.width) and [*net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.page.height*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.page.height) report's properties for this purpose. You can also use [*net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.width*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.width) and [*net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.height*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.height) pair of report's properties instead of the first one.
2. The second step. We known the page format size (for example in pixels. For A4 without margins it is: 555x802) and we set the number of characters in row and rows at page. We can calculate and set the exact values of *staticText* and *textField* elements positions (*x*, *y* coordinates and the *width* and *height* properties of element),

### The sample

#### Sample datasouce

I've used the *csv* datasource (*points.csv* file):

```
USER_NAME,LAST_ACCESSED,IS_ACTIVE,POINTS
John Doe,10/26/2013,Y,87.9
Sarah Connor,10/23/2013,Y,80.5
Viktor Navorski,10/14/2013,Y,95.5
Forrest Gump,10/25/2013,Y,97.0
Raymond Babbitt,10/24/2013,Y,88.5
Thomas Crown,10/24/2013,Y,88.0
Danny Ocean,09/30/2013,Y,90.5
```

#### The report design

I've remove the margin and set the *A4* report's format (555x802 pixels).

[image]

#### The jrxml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="text_output" language="groovy" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="9a0b1db2-1ed0-44e1-960b-4626cea0097d">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.page.width" value="80"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.page.height" value="40"/>
    <field name="USER_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LAST_ACCESSED" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="IS_ACTIVE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="POINTS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="43" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d065f8ed-0c05-47d0-a679-a392c9cfabe5" x="0" y="0" width="152" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[USER_NAME]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="573550a9-5fc9-41ee-ae4f-7b550868c75d" x="152" y="0" width="143" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[LAST_ACCESSED]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="4b1f5b5c-4c61-4159-9357-041fd8e3e775" x="295" y="0" width="138" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[IS_ACTIVE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="1c851f50-9ace-4e30-be1e-7d5454127db8" x="433" y="0" width="103" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[POINTS]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="7e358a83-b348-40ca-b6f4-009d6bed4b24" x="0" y="20" width="100" height="23"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[----------------------]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="523a7abd-0fbd-4b63-b8d5-2ed78ee795cc" x="295" y="20" width="100" height="23"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[---------]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="7ebe2ec7-9450-4fdf-b99a-48af5fe3ce49" x="152" y="20" width="100" height="23"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[-------------]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="155d3972-9d99-4d3b-bb41-05f08dcdd5fa" x="433" y="20" width="100" height="23"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[--------]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="652256e2-0f1e-4848-b1d0-d064caaa5020" x="0" y="0" width="152" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{USER_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="380af714-4dbd-4e0f-ae23-bfada0449a2f" x="152" y="0" width="143" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LAST_ACCESSED}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="752c0f18-2dea-4209-bd0d-d787d8c462a8" x="295" y="0" width="63" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{IS_ACTIVE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="40807ad0-58a4-42b7-9636-04f01c0c3bf5" x="433" y="0" width="54" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{POINTS}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

#### The result - generated txt file via JRTextExporter

I've used *iReport* for generating output file. The contents of this *txt* file is:

[image: The report generated as txt file]

### Using Java code

In case using *Java* code we should set for [*JRTextExporter*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRTextExporter.html) this parameters: [**JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_WIDTH**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRTextExporterParameter.html#PAGE_WIDTH) and [**JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_HEIGHT**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRTextExporterParameter.html#PAGE_HEIGHT)

The sample code:

```java
public static void generateReport() throws JRException {
    JRCsvDataSource dataSource = new JRCsvDataSource(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream(csvFileName));
    dataSource.setRecordDelimiter("\r\n");
    dataSource.setUseFirstRowAsHeader(true);
    dataSource.setColumnNames(new String[]{ "USER_NAME", "LAST_ACCESSED", "IS_ACTIVE", "POINTS"});

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, dataSource);

    JRTextExporter exporter = new JRTextExporter();

    exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_WIDTH, 80);
    exporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_HEIGHT, 40);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outputFileName);
    exporter.exportReport();
}
```

In this sample I've used the same *csv* file as datasource.

---

#### How we can calculate the x coordinate

In your sample you want to start the second column with 23 symbols. Ok, let see my sample. What we have:

- The page width is ***555*** pixels
- The number of characters in row is ***80***

The width of one character in this case is ***555/80=6,9375***.
We have 22 symbols before the first symbol in the 2nd column. It is *22*6,9375=152,625* pixels. In my sample I've set the *152* for the *x* property of 2nd column header. In my sample the first symbol in the header of the 2nd column has position *23*.

For the third column the calculated value is *43*6,9375=298,3125* and the real *x* in my sample is *295* (the 3rd column stars with *44* symbol).

As you can see the calculation is too accurate.

---

***Notes:***

You can find information about exporting to the text file here: [Text Export Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/text/index.html#textexport)

Comment: The solution is working fine, but I am facing difficulty is calculating the x,y co-ordinates and element width and height. For e.g., if the page width is 528 and 132 is the character limit, then 528/132=4px per character. So if I need the header to start at 25 position, then 24 * 4 = 96px is the x-coordinate and width is number of characters of the header multiplied by 4. Please let me know if this approach is right, since the position is not coming precisely.

Comment: @SurajM  I've just add info to my answer